# highcharts: shared tooltip not working for series with diffrent intervals

Tags: highcharts

I am using two data Series in a column chart and plotting them on time axis. The interval for one data series is 1 year and other series is three months.

I am trying to use shared tooltip, however its been only shared for the first point on X-axis, after that tooltip only displays data for one series.

Is there any workaround to Fix it?

Comment: But if you don't have points with the same value for x (timestamp) tooltip won't show more points. Shared tooltip works only when two points have exactly the same value for X.

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle ?

Comment: @pawal Fus: you are right, x needs to be same. But in my case its not, so is there any other approach I can take to solve this problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because as Pawel mentioned, the same x is needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            formatter: function() {
                var p = '';
                p += '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %e, %Y, %H:%M',this.x) +'</b><br/>';
                $.each(this.points, function(i, series){
                    p +='<span style="color:' + this.series.color + '">' + this.series.name + '</span>: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2) + ' kW<br/>'
                });

                return p;
            }
        }
```